# Is custom login page of Azure Active Directory possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm working on an .NET web application that uses Azure AD as an identity provider. Azure MFA is also used.

However, the user does not want to use the default Microsoft login page. Instead, they want to use a custom login page (hosted by us). It is possible?

Is there exist any API in Azure AD that authenticate user's credential? I tried this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/. But I cannot make it work on a web application.

Comment: First, the login page  cannot host by you. I'm not very clear about your scenario. How about [Add company branding to your sign-in page in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding). Did you try this ?

Comment: Hi Wayne, I imagine the custom login page will be a form. After the user enter his credential, we will pass this credential to Azure AD through some API to perform authentication. But I am not sure about if it is possible. For company branding, we have tried it. We will use this if there is no workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @KenLai: That is a scenario which is exactly what a centralized Identity Provider aims to stop. 

You don't want anyone other than the IDP handling the passwords. While it is possible to use username/password authentication in some instances, it is intended to be used by headless applications (daemons/services). 

You should not use it for regular user logins. 

With Azure AD Premium you can customize the login page heavily. My company and the last I worked for added giant company branded "hero images" next to and behind the login form.

Comment: @KenLai ,Well.For security and private , I DON't recommend this method. As Rasmus said, it should be avoided.  Though it's possible for technical, but it would be engaged to users private policy.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT to expand on the "technically possible solution". It's heavily discouraged for this use and is extremely brittle. The app will not be able to comply with MFA for example.

Comment: @DanielDobalian . Yes, you're right. This method  should be avoided and we discouraged for this. Also, when this scenario enables MFA, it won't work Indeed.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Just out of my curiosity, I found that there is Azure MFA SDK. Why it won't work?

Comment: @KenLai the big picture scenario will absolutely work with MFA, he was referring to the flow being described (resource owner password grant) in which you post the username and password in exchange for tokens.

Answer (score 3):

For this scenario, I recommend [Add company branding to your sign-in page in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding). It allows you to customize the appearance of the sign-in page with your company logo and custom color schemes.

But Company branding is available only if you upgraded to the Premium or Basic edition of Azure AD, or have an Office 365 license.

Additional: Building  login page and save usernames/password to authenticate with Azure AD in your Application is not recommended.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, it is possible with the ROPC grant flow, but not recommended as Wayne says. If your users have MFA enabled or need to log in to their ADFS for example, it will simply not work. Or if their password has expired. So it is just a bad idea usually.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the documentation recommends using Company Branding feature for customizing the pages provided by Azure AD.

If even then, if you want to show your custom HTML on Azure AD's login page, it is possible to add custom HTML for the login page.

- The requirement is your page should have `<div id="api"></div>`.
- Another requirement is this page should be hosted on CORS enabled, HTTPS public site.

Please [refer this blogpost](https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/03/23/creating-custom-login-page-in-azure-ad-b2c/) where I have shown how the custom HTML can be used.