# is it possible to create an sso azure ad without using the login.microsoft page

Tags: wordpress, azure-active-directory

i am new in azure ad
and i have been using sso plugin for azure ad to let my client user sigin into the wordpress
but this plugin make my client user login through microsoft login page
i have been looking for a solution to create a page that can bypass microsoft login page
but i cannot find anything except an sso using saml that using the same redirect method
and i kinda lost now
can anyone told me is it possible to create that kind of page?
if no is there any reason why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you use Azure AD Premium you can style it a lot, but it will still have much of the same look.

That is on purpose.

See the comments on this question: [Is custom login page of Azure Active Directory possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48179539/)